# How to find indexes of elements in recursive-knapsack?

Tags: c++, data-structures, knapsack-problem, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to implement recursive Knapsack which would return 2 things:

1. Max value we get by filling knapsack.
2. Indexes of the elements considered for filling the knapsack.

Please note that I don't want to use Dynamic Programming Approach to get this done (by reverse iterating the 2-D matrix to get the indexes of elements). I want to understand how it can be done in recursive knapsack approach?

This is what I have tried below (getting correct MaxValue (op#1) BUT not getting correct list of indexes (op#2)):

```
int knapsack(vector<int> wt, vector<int> val, int W, int N, vector<int>& idx)
{
    if (W == 0 || N == 0) return 0;

    if (wt[N - 1] <= W)
    {
        int  consider = val[N - 1] + knapsack(wt, val, W - wt[N - 1], N - 1, idx);
        int  dontconsider = knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);

        if (consider > dontconsider)
        {
            idx.push_back(N-1);
        }
        return max(consider, dontconsider);
    }
    else
    {
        return knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> wt = { 10, 20, 30 };
    vector<int> val = { 60, 100, 120 };
    int W = 50;

    vector<int> idx; // this should retain the indexes of the elements considered for knapsack.
    cout << knapsack(wt, val, W, wt.size(), idx);
    cout << "\nIndex of elements considered for knapsack: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++)
        cout << idx[i] << " ";

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected output should be:**

220

Index of elements considered for knapsack: 1 2

*Please help me. Thank you.*

Comment: Any comments/answers?

Comment: Can someone please look into my issue?

Comment: why my question is being ignored, I am wondering !!

Comment: Hello People! Please help me by answering this question. I am kindof stuck in recursion

Comment: Can anyone out there please look into it?

Comment: Dear community members, please let me know why my question is being ignored? if it is against the policy, then, please let me know that I have asked a wrong question and such questions don't receive any comments/answers. Expecting reply. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that if you don't attribute the bounty, the points will be lost, you will not get them back. If the answers are not satisfactory, you could explain why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector `idx` is passed by reference: `vector<int>& idx`.

The issue is that here:

```
int  consider = val[N - 1] + knapsack(wt, val, W - wt[N - 1], N - 1, idx);
int  dontconsider = knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);
```

This vector `idx` is modified twice.

One solution is to create a temporary vector for the first call...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int knapsack(const std::vector<int>& wt, const std::vector<int>& val, int W, int N, std::vector<int>& idx) {
    if (W == 0 || N == 0) return 0;

    if (wt[N - 1] <= W) {
        std::vector<int> idx0;
        int  consider = val[N - 1] + knapsack(wt, val, W - wt[N - 1], N - 1, idx0);
        int  dontconsider = knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);

        if (consider > dontconsider) {
            idx = idx0;
            idx.push_back(N-1);
            return consider;
        }
        return dontconsider;
    }
    else {
        return knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> wt = { 10, 20, 30 };
    std::vector<int> val = { 60, 100, 120 };
    int W = 50;

    std::vector<int> idx; // this should retain the indexes of the elements considered for knapsack.
    std::cout << knapsack(wt, val, W, wt.size(), idx);
    std::
    cout << "\nIndex of elements considered for knapsack: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++)
        std::cout << idx[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration be: std::vector<int> idx0=idx; ?

Comment: @HansOlsson In my understanding, at this point, the vector `idx` is always empty!

Answer (score 0):

Damien's diagnostic is correct. The problem is the repetition of already considered entries in the idx vector in the multiple evaluated branches of the iterations.

I would only add a new approach which I think would be more simple. Instead of using a vector, you can simply change your code making idx a set object, which is a container like a vector, but with one important difference: it does not allow repeated elements. So, if you insert an element already contained in a set, it will not add a new one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int knapsack(const vector<int> wt, const vector<int> val, const int W, int N, set<int>& idx)
{
    if (W == 0 || N == 0) return 0;

    if (wt[N - 1] <= W)
    {
        int  consider = val[N - 1] + knapsack(wt, val, W - wt[N - 1], N - 1, idx);
        int  dontconsider = knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);

        if (consider > dontconsider)
        {
            idx.insert(N-1);
        }
        return max(consider, dontconsider);
    }
    else
    {
        return knapsack(wt, val, W, N - 1, idx);
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> wt = { 10, 20, 30 };
    vector<int> val = { 60, 100, 120 };
    int W = 50;

    set<int> idx; // this should retain the indexes of the elements considered for knapsack.
    cout << "Maximum value obtained: " << knapsack(wt, val, W, wt.size(), idx);

    cout << "\nIndex of elements considered for knapsack: ";
    for (auto i : idx)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my example code using a set (note I had to make small adjustments, since there are some methods like pusk_back that are vector specific):